# Regexp - find my email Id end with valid domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am doing a email validation. I would like to test the `email` - the user entered properly end with some domain. usually the domain contains min 2 letters to max 3 letters. and it should prepended with `.` notation.

I tried like this, but not working properly

```
\.+{2}|{3}$
```

what is the correct approach to find this?

Comment: ...and now you have two problems ;) What about .info or .name TLDs?

Comment: may be i can increase the length to 6 at the end. then what else I do? and idea?

Comment: @3gwebtrain: Don't put a length limit on. You'll just end up having to deal with edge cases.

Comment: you have many answers to choose from. I would just use `<input type="email"/>` and call it a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be

```
/.+\..{2,3}$/
```

where

- `.+` says it should have 1 or more characters
- `\.` says there should be a `.`
- `.{2,3}` says there should be 2-3 chars(you can say something like `[a-z]{2,3}` to allow only alphabets)

Comment: `.info`........? Although I suppose the question specifically asks for 2 or 3, even though that's not correct...

Answer (score 0):

The pattern would be,

```
\..{2,3}$
```

Explanation:

- `\.` Literal dot symbol.
- `.{2,3}$` Allows two or three characters after the dot followed by the end of the string.